# 70s/80s scifi movie: astronauts return to future earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, astronauts

I remember seeing a movie when I was young (around late 80s) about a couple of astronauts returning to Earth. They either had some kind of an accident or fluke as there was some sort of time travel going on (or maybe parallel universe?) and they returned to a future Earth. (Note, future as in present day, like traveling from the 60s to 80s, not futuristic scifi-movie type future.)

I can't remember if there was any huge post-apocalyptic stuff but I remember at least two male astronauts walking in a desert and finding a can of coca-cola and going something like "at least we know we are in America" but they had never seen (aluminium) cans before and then they wondered what the can was made of as "it's too light to be metal" or something similar.

I remember enjoying the movie but sadly this is all the info I can remember.

It is NOT the following:

- Operation Ganymede
- Planet Earth
- Genesis II
- Strange New World

Comment: Aluminium cans pre-date the space age

Comment: I understand that, but nevertheless that was in the movie. They did not recognize the can. In hindsight, it is also possible that they were not astronauts but something else. The key point is that they recognized Coca-Cola brand, but not aluminium.

Comment: Steel coke cans were still common when I was a kid back in the early seventies.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this wasn't a Twilight Zone episode?  Was it color or black and white?

Comment: Note that in 1980, soda cans could be manufactured with much thinner walls than in 1940, making them much lighter. Even it it was the same material.

Comment: They were not astronauts, but two sailors.

Comment: A good movie reference for the change in cans is Jaws (1975), in which tough-guy Quint (Robert Shaw) demonstrates his toughness by crushing an empty drink can with one hand.These days any weakling can do that.

Comment: From Greg Egan's "Diaspora": _"What:?" "Replicator!" "It's just an empty canister." It was almost crushed flat, but there was still paint clinging to the metal in places, the colors faded to barely distinguishable grays ... it looked to ver like a 2D representation of a twisted ribbon. There was also part of a circle ... "PreIntrodus, this was pandemic. Distorted whole nations' economies. It had hooks into everything: sexuality, tribalism, half a dozen artforms and subcultures ... it parasitized the fleshers so thoroughly you had to be some kind of desert monk to escape it."_

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The scene with the Coke can is in *[The Philadelphia Experiment](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087910/)* (around 19m 40s into the movie).

The two guys were US Navy sailors from the 1940s caught up in an experiment which sent them to the 1980s.

While the scene with the coke can doesn't show up in [the trailer](https://youtu.be/iURHeZ3Qv8E?t=34), you can see the two men walking through the desert for several seconds about 34 seconds in.

Comment: @MartinGoldsack: the link you provided is to the 2012 made-for-TV movie. [OP may be referring to the 1984 feature film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087910/) The trailer link you provided was to the 1984 film, though.

Comment: Yes, it was the 1984 version. I only checked the trailer link.

Comment: Partially my fault. I didn't check the link when I embedded it.